# iterators to range of elements in a vector whose attributes have specific value

Tags: c++, stl, vector, g++

I have a vector of objects and I want to return the range of elements whose attribute have a specific value. This is the structure:

```
class A {
public:
  std::vector<B*> vec_;
  pair<vector<B*>::iterator, vector<B*>::iterator> getElements(unsigned int attr_val);
  unsigned int name() { return name_; }
private:
  unsigned int name_;
};

class B {
public:
  unsigned int attr() { return attr_; }
  A* source() { return source_; }
  B* dest() { return dest_; }
private:
  A* source_;
  B* dest_;
  unsigned int attr_;
};
```

The vector `vec_` is already sorted by `attr_` and `dest_->name()` (in that order). Now I want to return all elements, whose `attr_` is equal to `attr_val`.

What is the appropriate stl algorithm (or is there even a vector member function?) to implement `getElements(unsigned int attr_val)`?

Comment: Have you tried std::find ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a value to pass to `equal_range`, and the obvious thing to use is a pointer. The obvious way to get one is just to create an instance of `B` with the correct value of `attr_`, and write a comparator that involves only the value of `attr()`. I'm going to assume you already know how to do that since you managed to get the vector sorted ;-)

Provided there are no null pointers in the vector you could do this instead:

```
struct FindAttr {
    unsigned int attr;
    FindAttr(unsigned int attr) : attr(attr) {}
    bool operator()(B *left, B *right) {
        unsigned int leftval = left ? left->attr() : attr;
        unsigned int rightval = right ? right->attr() : attr;
        return leftval < rightval;
    }
};

...

return equal_range(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), nullptr, FindAttr(value));
```

You could make that a lambda:

```
return equal_range(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), nullptr, [=value](B *left, B *right) {
    unsigned int leftval = left ? left->attr() : attr;
    unsigned int rightval = right ? right->attr() : attr;
    return leftval < rightval;
});
```

You can actually cut out the pointer altogether, to give what I think is the "cleanest" solution:

```
struct FindAttr {
    bool operator()(B *left, unsigned int rightval) {
        return left->attr() < rightval;
    }
    bool operator()(unsigned int leftval, B *right) {
        return leftval < right->attr();
    }
};

...

return equal_range(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), value, FindAttr());
```

AFAIK there's no direct equivalent to this with a lambda, since lambdas can only have one call signature. I suppose you could write a lambda that takes a `boost::variant` (or any type that implicitly converts from both `unsigned int` and from `B*`, and that remembers which one it was).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `std::equal_range`, which basically does what you need. The interface is:

```
pair<It, It> equal_range(It first,
                         It last,
                         const T& value,
                         Compare comp);
```

`comp` defaults to `std::less`, which in turn calls operator `<`.

In your case, an implementation could be:

```
bool comparer(B* el, unsigned int value)
{
  return el->attr() < value;
}

pair<vector<B*>::iterator, vector<B*>::iterator> A::getElements(unsigned int attr_val)
{
  return equal_range(vec_.begin(), vec_end(), attr_val, comparer);
}
```

Comment: I found equal_range, but I wasn't sure how to provide the value, because it is supposed to be a `B*` but I want to provide an `unsigned int`

Comment: You'll either need to overload operator< in class B, write a functor to pass in, or use a lambda expression. Note also that you'll have to sort the vector first (using the same comparison as equal_range) in order for the returned range to be valid.

Comment: @user1801173 Sorry, fixed the implementation. As user673679 says, if your compiler supports C++11 you can use a lambda instead of writing a full function for the comparer.

Comment: `equal_range` can call the comparator both ways around.